# Bypass "Package Configuration" Screen

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, rabbitmq

I'm trying to setup my Ubuntu image via a script over on AWS and I can't get rabbitmq-server to install. It throws a Package Configuration screen that simply has one option (hit OK).

How can I bypass this? It causes my script to hang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your install script is being stopped by a `debconf` dialog. You can suppress the `debconf` dialog by setting the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` to `noninteractive`. For example:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

In general, if you want to script package installations using non-default configuration settings, you will need to preseed the `debconf` database with the desired settings. I recommend you read the [`debconf` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man7/debconf.7.html), and pay particularly close attention to the section titled "Unattended Package Installation".

Comment: YES YES! Thank you Steven. Great advice on debconf as well. I owe you a coffee (or beer)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use python fabric to do what you need.

In Stackoverflow, someone asked a question similar to yours so you can refer to that.

Here is the link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246256/python-fabric-how-to-answer-to-keyboard-input